# Turtle Key Bindings

Tags: python-3.6, turtle-graphics

So, I've written a program in turtle that draws using mouse-click binds, and I've created a bind to change the colour of the pen, but it only works once and I was wondering if there was a way so that the key-bind will call the function assigned to it every-time the key is pressed, rather than just once.

Here's my code currently:

```
from turtle import*

def Penoff(x,y):
    penup()

def Penon(x,y):
    pendown()

def colour():
    Colour = "white"
    Colour = textinput("Colour", "What Colour do you want to change to: ")
    color(Colour)


pensize(3)

setup (1000,600)
speed (8)


onscreenclick(goto)
onscreenclick(Penoff, btn = 2)
onscreenclick(Penon, btn = 3)


onkeypress(colour, "space")
listen()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `textinput()`, turtle makes its text input dialog the key event *listener*, so after the call you need to invoke `listen()` again to make your main window listen for key events:

```
def colour():
    Colour = textinput("Colour", "What Colour do you want to change to:")
    listen()
    if Colour:
        color(Colour)
```